# All my products show a special price based on a shopping cart rule that no longer exists

Tags: magento-1.7

I am very new to Magento.  Running version 1.702.  I was trying to implement a shopping cart rule.  Basically if the customer purchased more than 1 product, there is a $50 discount on the second product.  I tested with 1 single SKU.

It did not work, so I deleted the rule.  Now ALL my products are showing up with a SPECIAL PRICE.  The SPECIAL PRICE is a discount of $50 on the regular price.

... frustrated new user.

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me out.

J.Ribeiro
Toronto, Canada

Comment: Check to see if the rule still exist in promotion, it seem as if you deleted the Conditions and not the promo

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I've now removed everything, deleted all promotions from both Catalouge Pricing and Shopping Cart Pricing rules.  However, if I start typing to recreate the rule ... the name of the rule that caused the problem is cached.  I've cleared all caches and re-indexed countless times.  The Product Flat Data will not re-index (remains red).  Any help would be very, very appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this happen time and time again when the InnoDB engine has failed to start in MySQL and all your tables have defaulted to MyISAM. Check your table types, if they are MyISAM, there's your answer. Fixing it requires fixing your MySQL installation first, then using the Magento DB repair tool after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reindex have you tried directly removing the lock files?

`rm -rf public_html/var/lock/*`

Then try reindexing from the command line.  The magento indexer runs all indexes simultaneously and that can cause issues sometimes so pick the one you want to run and run it individually.

Run `php public_html/shell/indexer reindex -- one_from_below`

or `php public_html/shell/indexer --reindex one_from_below,two_from_below,etc,etc` to chain multiple of them together in comma separated list.

`catalog_product_attribute
catalog_product_price
catalog_url
catalog_product_flat
catalog_category_flat
catalog_category_product
catalogsearch_fulltext
catalogsearch_fulltext`

If that doesn't work then check the `salesrule` table in the database and see if the entry is still there for the price rule that you generated.

Comment: Can't thank you enough.  Is the entire system this buggy?  I'm really, really new at this.  May need to ask you some additional "stupid" questions but, thank you.

Comment: The entire system is buggy if you are new to it.  You get used to fixing the same things over and over again.  Indexing is a big issue in general and cache is as well.  Feel free to ask away.

Comment: Please also mark the correct answer as such :)

Comment: Hi again ... first thanks for the great advise.  I needed to be at least pointed in the right direction.  There was no "salerule" table but I found the table that contained the rules, emptied and it worked.

Comment: Now I'm back to where I started.  Can you help me setup the rule I was actually trying to do.  I have 3 products that are discounted $50 if they are purchased with any other product.  How do you do this??????

Comment: Hi Phil, could really use your help once again. I CANNOT get a shopping cart rule to work.  It is simple and I've checked all of the obvious stuff.  If there are more than 2 items in the shopping cart, 3 of my products should get a $50 discount.  I've followed online examples exactly ... no go.  If you could help, I'd be very greatful.